# Sort a list of lists using descending order, and then if there is a tie breaker, use descending order on another index in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

```
master_list = [["Hi", 2.00],["Hey", 6.01],["Hello", 9.56], ["How", 6.01]]
master_list.sort(key=lambda x: -(x[1], -x[0]))
```

I tried using this function to sort the master_list in descending order by the number, and if there is a tie, descending order by the string.
However, I get the error "TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
I don't know what I am doing wrong to get this error. How do I sort the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are applying a negation (`-`) on a tuple a string. Using `sorted` function, you can use `reverse=True` to sort the array in descending order.

```py
sorted(master_list, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
```